# How to use comparator with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I have an exercise to output all the strings that user inputs in ascending order. 
The program should stop when user enters "`quit`".

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Comparator;
   import java.util.Collections;
   public class Exercise2{
        public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word="string";
        while(!word.equals("quit")){            // cycle will continue till string will contain a word "quit".
             System.out.println("Please enter a string line. String can be whatever you want. After you enter a string please press Enter");
        word=scanner.nextLine();
        if(word.equals("quit"))
        break;
        list.add(word);
        }
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String o1, String o2){
                if(o1.length()>o2.length()){
                     return 1;
            }else{
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
    }

});

    System.out.println(list);
}
}
```

Could anyone explain why my code is not working?
 I would like to do it with Comparator, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "ascending order"?  How is that different than the natural ordering of `String`?  (and if it's not, why are you writing your own comparison function instead of using the natural order?)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you input? And then show both the expected output and what you actually get? This will help us understand what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Your compare dunction first checks if one String is longer than the other and if not you use compare by the natural order of the Strings. Not sure what the logic behind that is supposed to be. I would guess that this breaks the contract of the compare method.

Comment: Why do you need a Comparator? Did you try without it?

Comment: You can simply use `Collections.sort(list);` and that should work for you.

Comment: example if i input: "a", "abc", "ad" ,"abcdf", "abg" output should be: a,ad, abc, abg, abcdf

Comment: like procrastinator no need for Comparator just Collections.sort(list);          and Collections.reverse(list); for reverse order

Comment: Please put your example input and required output into your question. It's hard to spot in a comment and necessary to better understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator is violating the contract of `compare`, which states that if a > b then b < a must be true as well. However, if you'd pass "a1" and "b" you'd get 1 while if you'd pass "b" and "a1" you'd not get -1 but 1 as well.

Excerpt from the JavaDoc:

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.

You need to be consistent, i.e. if you want to compare the length first then you need to do that and only use the natural ordering when the lengths are equal:

```
 public int compare(String o1, String o2){
   //for Java 6 and below you could just do o1.length() - o2.length() 
   //as the return value doesn't have to be -1 or 1 but negative, 0 or positive
   int result = Integer.compare( o1.length(), o2.length() ); /
   if( result == 0 ) {
     result = o1.compareTo(o2);
   }
   return result;
 }
```

Comment: Guys I think my problem is that I do not really understand how collections.sort with comparator works. Please, could you send a link where it would be explained in detail on how to use it?

Comment: @Augustas you should get plenty of information on how that works on the internet, a simple search should be sufficient. However, the specifics actually don't matter. _The important point in your case is this: the sort algorithm will take 2 elements of your list and will call the comparator to see whether one is greater than the other or not_, then it moves them if necessary (but that's not important in your case). It's not important which elements are compared or in which order since from a logic point of view x > y should always be true if y < x.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, depending on what you want.

1) If you just want it alphabetically:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

2) If you want it sorted by length of each `String`:

**Edit:** added a clause if `String.length` is equal as per updated comments.

```
   Collections.sort(list, new java.util.Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                if(s1.length() != s2.length()){
                    return s1.length() - s2.length();
                }
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How would you sort "abc" and "abg" by length? See the OP's comment: he wants to make sure that "abc" is before "abg".

Comment: @Thomas I hadn't seen that that was necessary. Answer updated.